# Procesar mi GET en petición ajax

Tags: django, django-views

Hola tengo una consulta y una duda, estoy en una vista, al darle un botón hago el siguiente código

```html
function pagar_recibo(id) {
    $.ajax ({
        delay: 250,
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/general/recibo/add',
        data: {
            'id': id,
            'action_al': 'add_alumnos',
        },
    });
};
```

Dicho boton es un href que va a otra url, es decir que hace otra petición al server con GET
entonces en la nueva vista en el get_context_data tengo los siguiente

```html
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['arg'] = json.dumps(self.alum())
        # context['arg'] = self.alum()
        return context
```

y la función es la siguiente

```html
    def alum(self, **kwargs):
        data = []
        try:
            action = self.request.GET.get('action_al', False)
            print(action)
            if action == False:
                return
            elif action == 'add_alumnos':
                data = []
                id = int(self.request.GET['id'])
                Alumnos = Alumno.objects.filter(pk=id)
                for i in Alumnos:
                    item = i.toJSON()
                    item['text'] = i.get_full_name()
                    data.append(item)
                print(data)
        except Exception as e:
            data['error'] = str(e)
        return data
```

Así la recojo en el template

```html
window.data = {{ arg|safe }};
```

El problema está claro que una petición GET es vacía, que el cambio de url y la otra es la de ajax con la clave y valor dado, pero siempre me sale vacío el windows data, como podría solucionar eso?
Por favor necesitaría ayuda.
Saludos

Comment: Tu problema puede estar en que tus peticiones Ajax no hay un **success**, por lo tanto no se resuelve la petición, agrega mas contexto a tu pregunta, recuerda que puedes editarla las veces que sean necesarias.

Comment: Muchas gracias por constestar, le he puesto el success en la petición, pero no cambia nada. La petición AJAX la hace en un vista que se llama Alumno al darle a un botón en el envento onclick, al darle al boton se va a otra url, por lo tanto el servidor hace otra petición GET, yo solo quiero procesar una de ella. Cuando hago esto en el código. action = self.request.GET.get('action_al', False)
            print(action) La respuesta primera es False y la segunda esta todo mi data, pero al recogerlo en el template window.datos = {{ arg|safe }}; y luego en el js  let data = window.datos

Comment: En console.log(data), me sale por pantalla [] es decir vacío. Que necesita que añada? Realmente me da igual si es en GET o POST, lo que necesito es recoger esa data y luego poder acceder a ella en el js. Gracias de nuevo